# Parse XML file with Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I am trying to extract values from an XML file as per the following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
  <!-- SAP Data Services generated XML -->
  <!-- 2017-05-26.22:12:03(409,091)[1] -->

 <Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <CreatedAt>2017-05-26T22:12:11</CreatedAt>
 <CreateBy>BJOB_ODS_WF5MD_WEBSITE_FILES_5MIN_DATA</CreateBy>
 <StartDate>2017-05-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
  <DataSet Series = "5_Minute" ><Data><Value>10875.60</Value>
  </Data>
 ....
 <DataSet Series = "Actual" ><Data><Value>11150.00</Value>
  </Data>
 <Data><Value>10700.00</Value>  
</Data>
<Data><Value>10450.00</Value>
</Data>
   ...
</Data>
 </DataSet> 
</Root>
```

Hoping for the following output to csv but getting no love with the below script:

11150.00

10700.00

10450.00

```
 ****SCRIPT
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
#<DataSet Series = "Actual" ><Data><Value>11112.60</Value

my $file = '/var/data/Actual.xml' ||die $!;

my $t=XML::Twig->new();
$t->parsefile( $file );

# my @sets = $t->findnodes('//DataSet[@seriesName= "Actual" ]/set');
# I CHANGED THE ABOVE AND MODIFIED AS SHOWN BELOW

 my @sets = $t->findnodes('//DataSet[@Series= "Actual" ]/Value');    
 if (@sets) {
  my $outfile = '/var/csv/actual.csv';
  open my $out, ">", $outfile or die "Could not open $outfile: $!";  
  print { $out } $_->att('Value')."\n" for @sets;
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no `set` element in your XML, but your xpath expression asks for one. I can't try right now, but you should be good with `//DataSet[@seriesName= "Actual" ]/Data/Value`, and then don't use `$_->att` because `Value` is not an attribute. With the above xpath you'll have nodes and you can access the text property. I don't recall how, check the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a few misunderstandings here. Firstly, your XML isn't valid. I know it's just an example, but it would be good to give us a valid (if cut-down) example to use. And omitting the opening `<` from the first element makes me think you're not looking at this with quite the level of precision that you should!

Then the XPath expression bears very little relation to the XML that you're parsing. As simbabque mentioned in his comment, you're referring to elements that just don't appear in your XML, so it's not surprise that nothing is matching.

- The `seriesName` attribute is just called `Series`.
- There is no `set` element. You need `Data/Value`.

This seems to give you what you want (it's very close to simbabque's suggestion but he missed the `seriesName` problem).

```
my @sets = $t->findnodes('//DataSet[@Series="Actual"]/Data/Value');
```

Programmers need to deal in precision and accuracy. Perhaps you need to work on that a bit :-)

**Update:** Here is the test XML that I am using. It is based on your XML, but I've fixed a few obvious errors.

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <CreatedAt>2017-05-26T22:12:11</CreatedAt>
 <CreateBy>BJOB_ODS_WF5MD_WEBSITE_FILES_5MIN_DATA</CreateBy>
 <StartDate>2017-05-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
 <DataSet Series = "5_Minute" >
   <Data><Value>10875.60</Value></Data>
 </DataSet>
 <DataSet Series = "Actual" >
  <Data><Value>11150.00</Value></Data>
  <Data><Value>10700.00</Value></Data>
  <Data><Value>10450.00</Value></Data>
 </DataSet>
</Root>
```

And here is the code that I have tested it with. I've simplified your code slightly, taking the filename as an argument and writing the output to STDOUT (I don't understand why so many people hard-code filenames so much of the time).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $file = shift   or die "No file given\n";

my $t=XML::Twig->new();
$t->parsefile( $file );

my @sets = $t->findnodes('//DataSet[@Series="Actual"]/Data/Value');

if (@sets) {
  print $_->text, "\n" for @sets;
}
```

Note that I've made another change that I accidentally omitted from my original post - as 'Value' isn't an attribute, I've used `$_->text` instead of your `$_->att('Value')`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments (yes I hope to improve my programming skills)I have modified the script as indicated. However even with /Data/Value or simply /Value I am unable extract the numbers required.  I have added more of the XML but it is crazy big so I hope a captured enough this time.

Comment: Your sample XML is still invalid. There is a `<DataSet>` element with no corresponding `</DataSet>`. Please be more careful. I've updated my answer to include my test XML along with the code that I wrote. This gives the correct output.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I added the file out syntax and I am extremely happy.